# Azure DevOps Extension custom service endopint for ID/KEY

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I am developing Azure DevOps extension which contain service endpoint to hold secret ID/KEY. My requirement is to have endpoint just consist of Connection name, ID ,and Key in it.I have gone trough list of provided endpoints in Microsoft but I couldn't find suitable option to satisfy my requirement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=vsts#sep-ssh

closest solution I found is as below . But it contains input box for server URL(Which I need to omit (in this example though I don't define server URL it displays in popup dialog)). Please refer below image.

[image]

Is it possible to remove Server URL from above dialog box Or it there better endpoint type I can use for this requirement? please be kind enough to share some light with me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to create a custom service type, that will allow you to show/hide the individual text boxes. You can [find an example in the Azure DevOps Extension Tasks which I maintain](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-build-release-tasks/blob/master/vss-extension.json#L159-L210).

You define custom service endpoint types in the `vss-extension.json` along with your other extension points:

```
{
      "id": "vsts-marketplace-endpoint-type",
      "type": "ms.vss-endpoint.service-endpoint-type",
      "targets": [
        "ms.vss-endpoint.endpoint-types"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": "VstsMarketplacePublishing",
        "displayName": "Visual Studio Marketplace",
        "url": {
          "displayName": "Marketplace URL",
          "value": "https://marketplace.visualstudio.com",
          "isVisible": "false" 
        },
        "helpMarkDown": "Required permissions: <ul><li><b>Publish</b>: All accessible organisations, Marketplace (Publish)</li><li><b>Share</b>: All accessible organisations, Marketplace Publish</li><li><b>Install</b>: All accessible organisations or a specific organisation, Extensions (read and manage), Marketplace (acquire)</li><li><b>Query Version</b>: All accessible organisations, Marketplace (read)</li><li><b>Is Valid Extension</b>: All accessible organisations, Marketplace (read)</li></ul><br/><a href='https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/setup-admin/team-services/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate'>More information</a>.",
        "authenticationSchemes": [
          {
            "type": "ms.vss-endpoint.endpoint-auth-scheme-basic",
            "inputDescriptors": [
              {
                "id": "username",
                "name": "Username",
                "description": "Username",
                "inputMode": "textbox",
                "isConfidential": false,
                "validation": {
                  "isRequired": false,
                  "dataType": "string",
                  "maxLength": 300
                },
                "values": {
                  "inputId": "username",
                  "isDisabled": true,
                  "defaultValue": ""
                }
              },
              {
                "id": "password",
                "name": "Personal access token",
                "description": "Azure DevOps personal access token.",
                "inputMode": "passwordbox",
                "isConfidential": true,
                "validation": {
                  "isRequired": true,
                  "dataType": "string",
                  "maxLength": 300
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

You may find [other extensions that set or configure the authentication dialog on GitHub, there are quite a few](https://github.com/search?q=ms.vss-endpoint.service-endpoint-type&type=Code). Useful [docs are here in an old blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sriramb/2016/09/15/service-endpoints-customization/).

Comment: Thanks. I will try this

Comment: I just made "isVisible": "false" and it worked a charm